# setTimeout and V8

Tags: javascript, v8

I've installed V8 standalone and execute javascript code like this: `./d8 source.js`. When I use setTimeout I receive `ReferenceError: setTimeout is not defined`. Is this how it's supposed to be? Is it possible to somehow include this function?

Comment: I've never run V8 like this, but my intuition is that there is no `window` object, from which `setTimeout` would normally be called.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Your intuition is right and also wrong - everything is on window when the browser is the host environment, not just calls to browser APIs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`setTimeout` is not part of ECMA-262, it's implemented by the browsers. However, if you install [Node.js](http://nodejs.org) (which is V8 + extras) you will get a command line `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, V8 has its own `setTimeout` now (~7.5 years later), in the shell it provides. But it only takes one parameter (the function to call) and schedules it to be called once the current job is completed, roughly as though you'd passed `0` as the second parameter to the more familiar form of `setTiemout` provided by browsers and Node.js.

So given `example.js`:

```
console.log("a");
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("c");
}, 5000);
console.log("b");
```

then

```
$ v8 example.js
```

outputs

```
a
b
c
```

...with no appreciable delay between `b` and `c`.

(That example uses the `v8` command installed by [jsvu](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsvu), which is at least one way you run code directly in V8. I think `d8` got subsumed...)